# Circular table arrangements with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

We have 8 persons:
**A, B, C, D, 4E**

And we need to sit them on a circular table with these restrictions:

- Persons C and D can't be next to each other
- 4 Persons E can't be next to each other.

MY APPROACH:

I took all combinations $(8-1)! = 7! = 5040$
and eliminated from them all combinations of persons C and D where they are together, and all combinations where 4 persons E are together.

$(7-1)! = 6!*2!= 1440$

$(5-1)!= 4!*4! =776$

$5040-1440-776=2824$ combinations for sit them on circle table.

Is this a correct and right way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "4 Persons E can't be next to each other." Since you say **persons**, I presume the 4 are distinct, but do you mean that **all** 4 E's can't be next to each other or that **no** E's can be next to each other ? Pl. reproduce the exact question if you have paraphrased it.

Answer (score 0):

You are close - you seem to have overcounted the cases when both C and D sit next to each other and the 4 E people sit next to each other (i.e. you subtracted these possibilities once too many times). You should add this case back to your answer.

Comment: What if the combination of C and D together is $2!*3!$, and combinations with 4E together is $3!*4!$

Comment: The cases where C and D sit next to each other and the 4 E sit next to each other should be $(4-1)!*2!*4!=288$.

Comment: So final answer will be: $(6!*2!)-(3!*2!*4!)$?

Comment: No - you can use the work you have so far (getting to the $2824$), then we have to add the $3!*2!*4!$ back in. So we would have $2824+288=3112$ as our final answer.